# How to orderBy date by month from firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to `orderBy` month in ascending order from firestore? Say each document has a `date` field that contains the `month`(unordered).

**Example:**
`db.collection('dateExample').orderBy("date", "asc")`

**Result (Order by alphabets)**

`April, February, January, March, May....`

**What I want is to order by Months in ascending order**

**Example:**

`January, February, March, April, May,...`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should store your months as numbers instead of names.  Numbers have a very natural sort order based on their values.  Month names do not.